# How to flag an outlier(s) /anomaly in selected columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas

In the dataset `df` below. I want to flag the anomalies in all columns except `A`, `B`,`C` and `L`.

Any value less than 1500 or greater than 400000 is regarded as an anomaly.

```
import pandas as pd
  
# intialise data of lists
data = { 
         'A':['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5'],
         'B':[1,1,1,1,1],
         'C':[1,2,3,5,9],
         'D':[12005, 18190, 1034, 15310, 31117],
        'E':[11021, 19112, 19021, 12, 24509 ],
        'F':[10022,19910, 19113,19999, 25519],
        'G':[14029, 29100, 39022, 24509, 412262],
        'H':[52119,32991,52883,69359,57835],
         'J':[41218, 52991,55121,69152,79355],
         'K': [43211,8199991,56881,212,77342],
          'L': [1,0,1,0,0],
          'M': [31211,42901,53818,62158,69325],
        
        }
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# Print the output.
df
```

Attempt:

```
exclude_cols = ['A','B','C','L']

def flag_outliers(s, exclude_cols):
    if s.name in exclude_cols:
        return '' # or None, or whatever df.style() needs
    else:
        s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
        indexes = (s<1500)|(s>400000)
        return ['background-color: red' if v else '' for v in indexes]

df.style.apply(lambda s: flag_outliers(s, exclude_cols), axis=1)
```

Result of the code:

[image]

Desired output should look like this:

[image]

Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Are you looking for how to change the colour from `red` to `yellow`?

Comment: @MayankPorwal I am looking for how to skip columns 'B', 'C' and 'L' while flagging the rest. the color is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the subset as the argument of the apply function, you will get what you want.

```
exclude_cols = ['A','B','C','L']

def flag_outliers(s, exclude_cols):
    if s.name in exclude_cols:
        print(s.name)
        return '' # or None, or whatever df.style() needs
    else:
        s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
        indexes = (s<1500)|(s>400000)
        return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in indexes]

df.style.apply(lambda s: flag_outliers(s, exclude_cols), axis=1, subset=['D','E','F','G','H','J','K'])
```

[image]